# javascript-Html input tag in jquery dialog box is always giving undefined value in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created dialog box using jquery. The dialog box has two input fields and submit button.

Whenever I click the submit button the call is going to js function correctly. But it is not taking input values.

Sample.html

```
<a href="#"  class="view" >View</a>
<div id="dialogBox" title="details" style="display: none;">
<div id="list" class="ui-popup">

<label for="name">Add name</label><br/>
<input style="width: 50%;" type='text' id="name" value="" >
<input type="checkbox" id="db" /> <label for="db">click to add to DB</label><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="save" id="save" value="SAVE"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" class="cancel" id="cancel" value="CANCEL"/>

<ul>
<li>{{name}}</li>
<li>{{time}}</li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

name.js

```
var view= function( eventData )
{
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#dialogbox").dialog({resizable: false,
        height:'auto',
        width:950,
        modal: true}).css("maxHeight", window.innerHeight-200);
};

$('.view').click(view);

var update = function(e)
{
    var name = $("#name").val(); //undefined
    var db = $("#db").checked; //undefined
    params = {"function": "updatenames", "db": db};
    params['name'] = name;
    jQuery.post('api.py', params);

};

$('.save').click(update);

$('.cancel').click(function(e){
    var comment = document.getElementById('name').value = '';
});
```

The 'name' text box and the db check box always giving undefined in js .

Did I do anything wrong while trying getting value for those inputs?

Please share your suggestions

Comment: Replace `$("#name").val();` with `$("name").val();`

Comment: `$('db').checked` should also be `$('#db').is(':checked')`. Voted to close as the problem is simply due to typos.

Comment: I did typing mistake here..edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Your JQuery selector is wrong. It should be

```
$("#name").val();
```

Also, you probably want to do something like this:

```
$("#db").is(":checked");
```

EDIT: There are quite a few issues here. Look at your HTML syntax... at the label. You have wonky code:

```
DB</label<br><br>
```

You might want to check for simple things like HTML syntax issues first

Comment: @Nithya edited my answer. also check for your div open closing tags

Comment: It is my bad..while typing here I did all this..I so sry for that.

Comment: I think providing input in dialog popup is not consider by dom element.is that correct?

Comment: You need to give a lot more information. You seem to be using other libraries, i guess probably jqueryui, or bootstrap. Please set up the code in a fiddle/JSFiddle, then possibly the community can help you out in some way. Otherwise you will just get voted down.

Comment: I am using jquery ui.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $("name").val(); //undefined
var db = $("db").checked; //undefined
```

REPLACE with

```
var name = $("#name").val(); 
var db = $("#db").is(":checked"); //return true or false
```